# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for CKPresentationControllerRootViewController

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am showing too many gif images in UICollectionView. When I start scrolling collection view then it throws following error and cause the app crash too.
I am using [Gifu](https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu) to display gif images inside UICollectionViewCell. I have tried other libraries as well but got same error. Is there anything I am missing?

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for CKPresentationControllerRootViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue with library. I used [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage) and issue is resolved.